# Running Powershell Script as Scheduled task changes my document conversion. Why?

Tags: powershell, pdf, printing, automation, scheduled-tasks

I have a script that is converting .doc files to .pdf.  This is probably a somewhat different process than just your average document conversion process and i'll explain why.

I have document files that use a font family called "Myriad Pro".  This has caused an extreme amount of issues but can't be changed unfortunately.  The only way to convert this doc to PDF and have the PDF keep the text as SELECTABLE text not a bitmap image AND keep the font is to print as pdf.  I ended up selecting a program called Bullzip which acts as pdf printer instead of using the Microsoft PDF printer.  I had to do this because bullzip allows you to suppress almost every notification including the save as prompt. That was the main problem with Microsoft PDF printer.

All that works perfectly..When I run in the powershell ISE.  Here's the kicker. If i set this as a scheduled task and run with the option selected "Run whether the user is logged in or not".  This script runs with the default font.  Therein lies my problem.  Why is this happening? I can't understand this for the life of me.  If I run this as a scheduled task with the option selected "Run only when the user is logged in".  Everything works perfectly..

This is a very rare problem to have so I understand not a lot of people have experienced, but if anyone has please help.

Comment: Have you installed the Font family with Admin privileges ?

Comment: Is the task running as SYSTEM? Or a specified user?

Comment: It's running as a specified user.  specifically me.

Comment: Also i've installed the font family under my credentials.  Maybe I need to install them using the super user account?  Are fonts not shared?